# Calculation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$4$ complex numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ have the same, non-zero module $r$. Find the result of the following expression: $$|\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{a+b+c+d}|$$
I think this task is supposed to be solved by using trigonometrical expressions of complex numbers but that led me nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case $r=1$. Let $z=abcd$. Then the expression you have is
$$\left|z\cdot\frac{1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d}{a+b+c+d}\right|=\left|z\right|\cdot\left|\frac{\bar a+\bar b+\bar c+\bar d}{a+b+c+d}\right|=\left|\frac{\bar a+\bar b+\bar c+\bar d}{a+b+c+d}\right| $$
where $\bar k$ dentoes the complex conjugate of $k$. Note that this is true because the complex conjugate of a complex number with modulus $1$ is exactly its reciprocal. But for any complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ we have $\overline{z_1+z_2}=\bar z_1+\bar z_2$, so this is actually just
$$\left|\frac{\overline{a+b+c+d}}{a+b+c+d}\right|=\frac{|\overline{a+b+c+d}|}{|a+b+c+d|}=1.$$
Can you extend this approach to $r\neq 1$?

Comment: For r not equal to 1 I would need to use the distribution and express numerator as r^3(a'b'c'+a'b'd'+a'c'd'+b'c'd') and denominator as r(a'+b'+c'+d'), correct?

Comment: @Sans: Yes, that would be the first step.

Comment: Okay, then I can use the fact that modulo of a product is the product of modulos and put r^2 (r^3/r) on the outer sign. Then I will have r^2 multiplied by a similar expression but with r'=1 so, the answer will be r^2. Thanks a lot for help!